# Photoshop RAM usage

Tags: adobe-photoshop, user-experience, hardware

I have been using Photoshop for a long time now, the version i'm using right now is CC 2017.

I've been always asking myself, why is it using so much ram and the .psd files, when saved occupy so much memory. For example i have 7 layers, each of which is an image that weighs 3-4 Mb on the HDD, so that's a total of 21-28 Mb of raw files + some hundreds for the software itself, logically, the RAM usage shouldn't go over 500 Mb or so. The RAM usage goes above 1500 Mb and the rounded project file size goes somewhere around 400 Mb. How can be this explained?

Comment: I will assume this is a question for Adobe to answer

Answer (score 1):

A PSD file is usually compressed on HDD. Opening the file will decompress it so it will be larger. There is Undo/History that has to be stored somewhere, which means many more versions of the file.

I'm no technician, but I think PS uses all RAM it can get from the OS, because RAM is the fastest possible way to handle things. If there is not enough RAM to hold all data, it will use the HDD as scratch disk, which can get very slow, depending on the HDD/SSD.